# Plotting open loop gain and GBP of an opamp in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

How can I plot the "open loop gain" versus frequency of an opamp in LTspice?

And how can I plot the gain bandwidth product as well?

Is the following correct?:

[image]

Comment: http://www.linear.com/solutions/4449

Comment: Have you run the simulation and checked the output? Does it match what you expect?

Comment: You don't plot gain bandwidth product - it is a number and not a graph.

Comment: Please check-out the circuit I gave here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/297189/determining-open-loop-gain-of-an-opamp-in-ltspice?rq=1 You need to provide the exact dc bias level to prevent the op amp output from railing up or down and doing that manually with high-loop gain op amps is an impossible exercise. The simple added circuit does that automatically and it works like a charm.